# Startup glitch - many base OS functions gone

Tags: 16.04

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Pa4I7HFoA3VGo4dkdpUmJxMTg/view?usp=drivesdk

I was messing around with my bashrc trying to install the powerline plugin (which works fine,) and I experienced this startup glitch. Unity won't start, menu on top allowing me to view settings and all is gone, and open/close function on all windows is gone. The only thing I can do is open terminal (that too with right click into "open terminal," ctrl+alt+t does not work) and open some base windows like wallpaper change.

This problem's been there before for a few times but always fixed itself about 5 secs into login or at least upon restart (I've tried restart with power button and "sudo shutdown now" - nothing.)

Edit: fixed. It was a Unity problem (for whatever reason, it wasn't starting.) Had nothing to do with my bashrc. For anyone who sees this thread and has a similar problem:

sudo apt-get purge unity

sudo apt-get install unity

reboot

That's what worked for me.

Comment: Try undoing the powerline changes from recovery mode then see if you can fix it as usual, else it not from powerline

Comment: Nope, not from powerline.